# ClassCastException when accessing array of type Object[]

Tags: java

Please consider the following piece of Java code (I have taken it from real world but simplified a bit and removed irrelevant details):

```
public class CastIssue<T> {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private T[] data = (T[]) new Object[1];

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final CastIssue<Integer> issue = new CastIssue<>();
    System.out.println(issue.data.length);
  }
}
```

It compiles fine but throws the following exception when executed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    at CastIssue.main(CastIssue.java:7)
```

On the other hand if I add explicit cast to Object[] it works without exception:

```
public class CastIssue<T> {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private T[] data = (T[]) new Object[1];

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final CastIssue<Integer> issue = new CastIssue<>();
    System.out.println(((Object[])issue.data).length);
  }
}
```

Why does exception is thrown in the first case?

I use JDK 1.8.0_40

EDIT: as noted by @wero, compiler inserts a cast in the first case. I want to understand why that cast is inserted there (sorry for not stating this explicitly in the original question). Any references to JLS or JVM specification would be good.

Comment: Parent type can hold a child type..otherwise you have to do explicit type casting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of type erasure, `T` is actually an `Object` in the non-static methods of `CastIssue`. In the `main` method, `T` is known to be `Integer`, so the `issue.data` reference is implicitly cast to an `Integer[]`.

An `Integer[]` is a subclass of an `Object[]`, in the same way `Integer` is a subclass of an `Object`.

You can assign an `Integer` to a variable of type `Object`, but you cannot cast/assign an `Object` to a variable of type `Integer`.

Same goes for the arrays: You can assign an `Integer[]` to a variable of type `Object[]`, but you cannot cast/assign an `Object[]` to a variable of type `Integer[]`.

---

So, how do you do it, with generics?

In order for the code to construct an actual instance of `T`, or a `T[]`, it must be given the actual `Class` of whatever `T` is supposed to be at runtime.

You can pass in that class on the constructor, and use reflection to create the array:

```
private T[] data;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public CastIssue(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.data = (T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, 1);
}
```

Your main method will then be:

```
final CastIssue<Integer> issue = new CastIssue<Integer>(Integer.class);
System.out.println(issue.data.length);
```

Specifying `Integer` twice on the constructor seems redundant, and sure it can be collapsed with the diamond operator (`new CastIssue<>(Integer.class)`), but still...

You can use a generic static method to let the compiler infer the type (`T`) from the parameter:

```
public static <T> CastIssue<T> create(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new CastIssue<T>(clazz);
}
```

This way the main method becomes:

```
final CastIssue<Integer> issue = create(Integer.class);
System.out.println(issue.data.length);
```

Whether that's better is for you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

In the compiled class the type of the field `private T[] data` is `Object[]` due to type erasure.
But when you access it (`issue.data.length` in your first example) it is casted to a Integer array. This is easy to see when you decompile the class with `javap`:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #1                  // class test/CastIssue
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #24                 // Method "<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: getstatic     #25                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      11: aload_1
      12: getfield      #14                 // Field data:[Ljava/lang/Object;
      15: checkcast     #31                 // class "[Ljava/lang/Integer;"
      18: arraylength
      19: invokevirtual #33                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      22: return
```

When you cast it to an Object array (your second example), the `checkcast` operation is dropped and the error does not occur:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #1                  // class test/CastIssue
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #24                 // Method "<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: getstatic     #25                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      11: aload_1
      12: getfield      #14                 // Field data:[Ljava/lang/Object;
      15: arraylength
      16: invokevirtual #31                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      19: return
```

Comment: Yes, I see that cast happens. I'm curious to know why it is inserted there by the compiler when I access length property of the array. Some references to JLS or JVM specification would be good. I should probably edit my question to state it more explicitly.

Comment: @AndriiPolunin I believe I kind of covered that in the first paragraph of my answer, though without any reference to JLS. Hope that helps.